# Accuracy of a Binomial Expansion

Tags: approximation, binomial-theorem, estimation

(Adapted from a recent A-Level question. I think there is more to this than $\lvert -\frac{1}{2}\rvert <\lvert2\rvert$. Specifically I think you need to take account of the fact that they evaluate different (rational) multiples of $\sqrt{2}$. Is that correct, and if so what would a full explanation be?)

The first three terms in ascending powers of $x$ of the binomial expansion of $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x}}$$ can be used to find an approximation to $\sqrt{2}$.

Substituting $x=2$ gives $$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Substituting $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ gives $$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$$

Without evaluating your expansion, say which of these leads to the most accurate approximation of $\sqrt{2}$. Explain your answer fully.

Comment: The question is not clear. I suggest you rephrase it. What are you asking exactly?

Comment: Is this really about the binomial expansion? This is more about Taylor expansion.

Comment: @SurferRosa did you try to analyze the reminder?

Comment: @dcolazin Thanks. Yes, I have but I can't get to the bottom of it. I've spent at least a couple of hours on it. I treated the three term expansion/approximation as a function a(x) then tried to compare what happened when you evaluate a(x) at -1/2 and 2 and how they differ from (the rational multiples of) sqrt(2), but lost track.

Comment: @dcolazin

Ok. Here goes. The expansion is a(x) + r(x) ie the three term expansion plus remaining terms.



For x = 2

sqrt(2) = 2*a(2) + 2*r(2)

For x = -1/2 

sqrt(2) = 3*a(-1/2) + 3*r(-1/2)

mod(3*r(-1/2)) < mod(2*r(2))

therefore -1/2 is a closer approximation.

Comment: @SurferRosa now, can you motivate the last disequality of the two absolute values?

Comment: @dcolazin. You know this question was worth 1 mark... Right let's see, let r(x) = mx^3 + nx^4+... and then, for instance, compare r(2) and (3/2)*r(-1/2). Assuming that's right, I know it needs tidying up and finishing off but if it is all basically correct then I think I've got the answer I was looking for, ie there **is** more to it than mod (-1/2) < mod (2). Thanks for the prompts, they really are appreciated.